# extracting the second observation from a character vector in a data frame

Tags: r

Extract the second observation from a `c()` vector in a data frame.

I have some data which looks like:

```
                          splitNames
1  , grupo, modelo, s.a.b., de, c.v.
2                         , gymboree
3                           , cerner
4     , stellus, capital, investment
5         , cambium, learning, group
6               , cornell, companies
7                      , the, boeing
8                        , wd-40, co
9                         , glencore
10                    , the, valspar
```

I want to extract `grupo`, `gymboree`, `cerner`, `stellus`, `cambium`, `Cornell`, `the`, `wd-40`, `Glencore` and `the` from the data. Currently I can do it but it only extracts `grupo` from the data. `y %>%  mutate(splitNames[[1]][[2]])`

Data:

```
structure(list(splitNames = list(c("", "grupo", "modelo", "s.a.b.", 
"de", "c.v."), c("", "gymboree"), c("", "cerner"), c("", "stellus", 
"capital", "investment"), c("", "cambium", "learning", "group"
), c("", "cornell", "companies"), c("", "the", "boeing"), c("", 
"wd-40", "co"), c("", "glencore"), c("", "the", "valspar"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your data structure, you could use:

```
sapply(data$splitNames, function(x) x[2])

 [1] "grupo"    "gymboree" "cerner"   "stellus"  "cambium"  "cornell" 
 [7] "the"      "wd-40"    "glencore" "the"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can alo use `[` without anonymous function

```
sapply(data$splitNames, `[`, 2)
#[1] "grupo"    "gymboree" "cerner"   "stellus"  "cambium"  "cornell"  "the"      "wd-40"    "glencore" "the"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the Tidyverse anyway you could also do it this way:

```r
library(purrr)
       
map_chr(data$splitNames, 2)
#>  [1] "grupo"    "gymboree" "cerner"   "stellus"  "cambium"  "cornell" 
#>  [7] "the"      "wd-40"    "glencore" "the"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>